# purge-chain for local testnets requires rococo-native feature enabled

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, substrate-parachain-template, cleanup

I completed the [Connect a local parachain tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-parachain/#chain-purging) and during cleanup `purge-chain` for the collator node failed:

```
% ./target/release/parachain-collator purge-chain --base-path /tmp/parachain/alice
Error: Input("Relay chain argument error: Invalid input: `rococo-local` only supported with `rococo-native` feature enabled.")
```

I've followed the tutorial successfully, had no issues and never came across "`rococo-native` feature".
Do you have an idea what is going on and how I can properly purge the chain?
(I can always `rm -r`, I guess, but I wanted to know if I failed to configure something)

---

Since asked in the comments, the way I start the parachain collator node is as in the tutorial:

```sh
./target/release/parachain-collator \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain ~/projects/rococo-custom-2-raw.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

I tried

1. manually (`rm -r`) removed the parachain directory in `/tmp/parachain/alice`
2. started the node (starting a new chain db)
3. stopped the node (`ctr+C`)
4. I tried to purge the chain with the same command as above - still resulting in the same error.

The only place I see `rococo-local` is in the chain config file - `rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json` - I created it using the commands in the tutorial but it may be worth going down in that direction to find more info.

Comment: I see the tutorial has: `--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json` in earlier steps. Can you add that to the `purge-chain` instruction and see if it gets rid of the error?

Comment: Thank you @ShawnTabrizi but sadly the error is still there. I tried removing `--base-path` and using just `--chain` and I also tried with both at the same time - the error is the same.

Comment: can you provide a minimal number of commands to reproduce?

Comment: I added the command used to start the node. So, it's basically 1. start the node 2. stop the node 3. purge the chain

Comment: It may be in the way I created the rococo-local chain configs for both parachain and relay chain but I don't recall doing anything different from the tutorial...

Comment: I had the same issue, how I solved I don't know, it was just a matter of trying a couple of times. For dev purposed I use the `--tmp` flag instead of `--base-path` so I don't have to purge chain content on each run.

Comment: @andresvsm thank you for the input! I'm also not really concerned with the issue since I'm still learning and I'm doing the tutorials but decided to share it in case it would help the community somehow.